# how do I use and set custom variables from within a Handlebars.js block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

So lets say I have this json

```
food = [
  {
    name: "banana",
    type: "fruit",
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    name: "apple",
    type: "fruit",
    color: red"
  },
  {
    name: "strawberry",
    type: "fruit",
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    name: "carrot",
    type: "vegetable",
    color: "orange"
  },
  {
    name: "chocolate",
    type: "dessert",
    color: "brown"
  }
]
```

And I want to display it in a table like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#each food}
    {{#if lastType == "" or lastType != type}}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">{{type}}
    </tr>
    {{/if}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{Color}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But I want to add another table row for each time there's a new value for the property of type. So basically the finally table would look like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">fruit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>banana</td>
        <td>yellow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>apple</td>
        <td>red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>strawberry</td>
        <td>red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">vegetable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>banana</td>
        <td>yellow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">dessert</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>chocolate</td>
        <td>brown</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How could I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objective is to display your foods in groupings with the type as the group's heading. I would advise *against* putting the logic to do this grouping in the template as this will be cumbersome to achieve. The better solution - one that would keep the template clean and clear - would be to do the grouping on the data *before* sending it to the template.

The ideal data structure would have the foods indexed by their type. We could achieve this with an Object like the following:

```
{
    "fruit": [
        {
            "color": "yellow",
            "name": "banana",
            "type": "fruit"
        },
        {
            "color": "red",
            "name": "apple",
            "type": "fruit"
        }
    ],
    "vegetable": [
        {
            "color": "orange",
            "name": "carrot",
            "type": "vegetable"
        }
    ],
    "dessert": [
        {
            "color": "brown"
            "name": "chocolate",
            "type": "dessert"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this data structure, it would be simple to get the groupings in our template using nested `{{#each}}` blocks. (I am assuming we have named our Object, "foodsByType")

```
{{#each foodsByType}}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">{{@key}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{#each this}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{color}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

If you are looking for a nice way to construct the `foodsByType` Object, you could consider using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const foodsByType = food.reduce((acc, foodItem) => {
    if (!acc[foodItem.type]) {
        acc[foodItem.type] = [];
    }
  
    acc[foodItem.type].push(foodItem);
  
    return acc;
}, {});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ck54j1dq/) for your reference.

Comment: Yeah this was way easier than the way i was trying to do it. Worked like a charm. Thanks!